# R Mysql dbconnect parameters

Tags: mysql, r

I am running a R procedure that connect to a **MySQL database** using the package **RMySQL**, and all is working well. But now I want to run the same procedure trough **RSCRIPT**, and want to pass connection parameter, like this

```
library(RMySQL)
con_str <- "MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'nepal_statagri', host = 'localhost'" (this is the string I want to pass as a parameter to RScript)
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(con_str)
```

but it doesnt work, and I get a message:

> "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable):  unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature
>   ‘"character"’".

What can I do ?

Comment: `RMySQL` `dbConnect` does not have a version which can accept a single connection string of this format.  You will have to parse the input string in your R script or possibly use MySQL groups.

Comment: I have tried this way, but the result is the same. Or maybe you can give mi an example ?

Comment: Look at the answer given by @sinQueso below, you need to either fix your syntax or use groups, the RMySQL API won't allow you to do what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message indicates, you are trying to connect to your database by passing it a character vector. That won't work.

One option would be to use the correct syntax in your script:

```
library(RMySQL)
mysqlconnection <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                            user = 'root',
                            password = '',
                            dbname = 'nepal_statgri',
                            host = 'localhost')
```

However, you mention using Rscript. So my understanding, is that you're interested in having a R file that doesn't store the details of your connection, but instead you want to pass these details as arguments from a shell terminal.

One option to do that is to use the package [`docopt`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R) that allows you to easily create command line interfaces for your R scripts. For instance, if you save the following in a file called `connect_mysql.R`:

```
'usage: connect_mysql.R [--user <user> --password <pwd> --db <database> --host <host>]

options:
  --user username
  --password password
  --db database
  --host host
' -> doc

library(docopt)
library(RMySQL)

opts <- docopt(doc)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
          username = opts$user,
          password = opts$password,
          dbname  = opts$db,
          host  = opts$host)
dbListTables(con)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

you'll then be able to call it using Rscript and pass your connection details:

```
Rscript connect_mysql.R --user root --password password --db nepal_statgri --host localhost
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I need ! BUT .... I have downloaded from CRAN both packages DevTools and Docopt and installed them, but I cannot run them because they require other packages; I had tried one by one and insalled Memoise, Digest, Httr, Withr, R6 .... and it seem a never ending story. Is tehre a place where I can get all the dependencies ?

Comment: `docopt` is available from CRAN and has minimal dependencies. If you type `install.packages("docopt")` at your R terminal, all the dependencies will be installed. You don't need `devtools` to install it (it's only if you want to install the latest version from github).

Comment: perfect !   I dont know why I was following the instructions for github .... Thank you very much, it is  really useful for my job

Comment: sorry but I am not able to run it.   when i issue the Rscript command at command line with all my parameters (exactly as you wrote), only the usage is printed on the screen, and nothing happens. Which is my error ?

Comment: It turns out that using `-h` is not possible because it clashes with arguments that are provided by `R` (and therefore `Rscript`) and they are intercepted before they can be passed to `docopt` (see [here](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R#note)). I updated my answer to use longer argument names to avoid encountering this issue.